# Структура каталога в адресной строке

Tags: php, javascript, html

При создании каталожной структуры на сайте, в некоторых сайтах он дублируется через адресную строку.
Например сайт auto ru

https://m.auto.ru/mototsikly/all/

Если посмотреть, то каждый переход по разделу сопровождается сменой каталога и в адресной строке.

Как это организованно?
Очевидно что генерацией адресной строки через php либо js

А как это делать правильно? 
То есть наличие каталожности в адресной строке позволяет делиться ссылкой непосредственно в нужную часть каталога.

Адресную строку можно обрабатывать через php header либо через js location.
Как все-таки правильно это организовать? Спасибо за комментарии и подсказки.

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался. Из всех загугленных решений, это мне показалось наиболее лаконичным http://epsiloncool.ru/programmirovanie/php/samyj-prostoj-i-logichnyj-chpu-dlya-php

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: Допишу развёрнутый ответ как буду готов. Пока и найденное решение не идеально.